# If I lose my central tile, do I lose the round?

Tags: galaxy-trucker

I was playing a game of Galaxy Trucker the other day when one of the players took a small meteor to his exposed central tile.  He had a number of other occupied crew pods, but I was under the impression that if you lose your central crew pod, your ship is destroyed and you lose the round.

If I lose my central crew pod and still have other crew members left, can I continue on with the remainder of my ship, or do I lose right away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four cases where you give up:

1. If you choose to give up (which you can only do before revealing the next adventure card).
2. If you reach an Open Space card with zero engine power.
3. If an adventure card leaves you with no human crew on board.
4. If you are lapped in turn order (i.e. the player in the lead loops around the board and overtakes you) [courtesy of Samthere]

While the most obvious place to have human crew is in your starting tile (and indeed it will always start with two humans in it, never an alien), if you have another crew cabin with humans in it as part of your ship then it doesn't matter if you lost the starting tile or the crew in it, you can continue your flight.

Comment: There's a fourth case too; if you get lapped in the flight order. :)

Answer (score 5):

No, there's nothing special about your starting piece other than its shape and not being able to hold aliens. As long as you have crew (and engines if you hit open space) you can keep going.